# Boost Beast async_write() With Queue

Tags: c++, asynchronous, queue, boost-beast

I have the following code:

```
std::queue< nlohmann::json > outgoingMessages;

void session::do_write( void ) {
    if ( outgoingMessages.size() > 0 ) {
        auto message = outgoingMessages.front();
        outgoingMessages.pop();

        ws_.async_write( boost::asio::buffer( message.dump() ), boost::beast::bind_front_handler( & session::on_write, shared_from_this() ) );
    }
};

void session::on_write( boost::beast::error_code errorCode, std::size_t bytes_transferred ) {
    if ( errorCode )
        return fail( errorCode, "write" );

    if ( bytes_transferred == 0 )
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 1 ) );

    do_write();
};
```

What I need it to do is only write when there is data to write. The problem is, when the queue is empty, `async_write()` never gets called, breaking the loop. Works great until it runs out of queue items to send.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by recursively calling `do_write()` and check wether or not the queue contains new items. As long as you are making sure that `async_write()` is not called concurrently, you should be fine.

Try changing your code to:

```
std::queue< nlohmann::json > outgoingMessages;
bool isWriting = false;

void session::do_write( void ) {
    if ( !isWriting && outgoingMessages.size() > 0 ) {
        isWriting = true;
        auto message = outgoingMessages.front();
        
        ws_.async_write( boost::asio::buffer( outgoingMessages.dump() ), boost::beast::bind_front_handler( & session::on_write, shared_from_this() ) );
    } else
    {
        // Repeat write
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        do_write();
};

void session::on_write( boost::beast::error_code errorCode, std::size_t bytes_transferred ) {
    if ( errorCode )
        return fail( errorCode, "write" );

    if ( bytes_transferred == 0 )
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( 1 ) );

    outgoingMessages.pop();

    // Repeat write for additional messages
    if (!outgoingMessages.empty())
    {
        ws_.async_write(
            boost::asio::buffer(outgoingMessages.front()),
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_write,
                shared_from_this()));
    }
    else
    {
        isWriting = false;
        do_write();
    }
};
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `sleep_for()` in an `boost::asio` async handler. Handlers should finish the work, that they have to do, and then always return immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You have to synchronize access to the write queue, so that threads adding to it and threads removing from it don't get into each other's way!

The easiest way to do this, is to use the websocket's strand:

```
class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
    websocket::stream<beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream>> ws_;
    std::queue<std::string> outgoingMessages;
    bool isWriting { false }
    // More data fields omitted

    // Code for connecting the websocket etc. omitted

    // Write out the next pending message, if no write is active:
    void do_write(void) {
        if(! isWriting && ! outgoingMessages.empty()) {
            auto message = std::move(outgoingMessages.front());
            outgoingMessages.pop();
            ws_.async_write(boost::asio::buffer(std::move(message)),
                            boost::beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_write, shared_from_this()));
        }
    }

    void on_write(boost::beast::error_code errorCode, std::size_t) {
        isWriting = false;
        if(errorCode)
            return fail(errorCode, "write");
        do_write();
    }

public:
    // Access to the websocket is serialized by a strand!
    session(boost::asio::io_context& ioc, boost::asio::ssl::context& ctx)
      : ws_(boost::asio::make_strand(ioc), ctx) {}


    // May be called from any thread, but dispatches the actual enqueuing
    // to the websocket's strand to ensure thread safety:
    void enqueue(const nlohmann::json& jsonmessage) {
        boost::asio::dispatch(ws_.get_executor(), [msg=jsonmessage.dump(), self=shared_from_this()] () mutable
        {
            self->outgoingMessages.emplace(std::move(msg));
            self->do_write();
        });
    }
};
```